# SQL Server 2005 insert xml version and namespace at start of xml doc

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005, namespaces

I'm trying to insert the version & namespace info to an xml doc created in my sql 2005 query.

I've tried declaring an xml variable and assigning the literal to it.  Not sure if I have to use with namespaces or can do something like this:

```
DECLARE @doc2 XML;

SET @doc2 =N'<ActionChangeRequest

xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

    xmlns="http://www.customersite.com/xmlapi">
    </ActionRequest>'

SELECT @doc2,
+
    SELECT
      (  SELECT .....
    FROM    tbl A1
    FOR  XML PATH('Customer'),  TYPE ),
      ( SELECT  ......
    FROM tbl        A2
    FOR  XML PATH('RepairFacility'), TYPE),
      ( SELECT .....                             
    FROM tbl J
    FOR  XML PATH('Action'),     TYPE    )
    FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('Element')
```

Comment: SQL Server?  Also, you want everything after DECLARE to be in a code block, yeah?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you want the XML to look like but using [WITH XMLNAMESPACES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177607%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) the query would look something like this:

```
;with xmlnamespaces( default 'http://www.customersite.com/xmlapi',
                    'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' as xsd,
                    'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as xsi
                    )
select '' as '*'
for xml path(''), root('ActionRequest')
```

Result:

```
<ActionRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               xmlns="http://www.customersite.com/xmlapi"></ActionRequest>
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do is insert or paste the answer to the beginning of the document.  When I add the 'select ' ' as '*' etc the browser doesn't see it an xml

Comment: `select '' as '*'` is just there to show you how to use `with xmlnamespaces` since I have no idea what you want your XML to look like. You probably can't just add this node at the beginning because that would create an invalid XML document. Unless you are looking for a XML fragment. Please update your question with how you would like your XML to look like.

Comment: I'm adding the select as 'select '' as '*' for xml path + rest of select.  If I include the for path I get an error if I don't it's not xml.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<Elements><?xml version=”1.0” encoding=”utf-8”?><xmlns:xsd=”http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema” xmlns:xsi=”http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance” xmlns=”http:// www.customersite.com/xmlapi”><AccessKey></AccessKey>-<Element><Customer/><RepairFacility/><Promise/></Element>-<Element><Customer/><RepairFacility/><Promise/></Element></Elements>

Comment: @MarkP - Eh? 1. Two sections with `<xml? version...`? XML in SQL Server can have none. You have to add **one** of that in some client that saves the XML to disk or something. 2. The namespaces has to be part of an element. Perhaps the root element `<Elements>`? 3. Update your question instead of writing in the comment section. It will make the question more clear and also it will give other people a chance to answer/see that this question has some action.